# Почему переменная не меняется при повторном вызове функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number = 150
number2 = 0
var = False

def fun(num):
    global var
    if number == 160:
        var = True
    else:
        var = False

while True:
    number += 1
    number2 += 1
    fun(number)
    fun(number2)
    if var == True:
        print('yes')
```

мне нужно что бы когда какое либо число доходило 160, переменная менялась, но это работает только на одном числе. почему? и как это исправить? так же позже нужно проверять другие числа

Comment: а выход из `while True` когда?

Comment: лучше бы вы не правили код. Вы пробовали запустить, то что вы опубликовали?

Comment: S.Nick да я пробовал запустить, но мне нужно что бы переменная меняла значение на True после того как число будет 160, но работает это только на первом числе, а мне нужно что бы когда оба число достигали 160 переменная становилась True а потом опять менялась на False

Comment: глобальные переменные - это зло. Вызывайте функцию так: `var = fun(number)`. Из функции возвращайте результат так: `return var`. Проверяйте так: `if var:`.

Comment: S.Nick вы имеете в виду так ?

number = 150
number2 = 0

def fun(num):
    if number == 160:
        return var
    else:
        return False

while True:
    number += 1
    number2 += 1
    var = fun(number)
    var = fun(number2)
    if var:
        print('yes')
    print(var, number, number2)

Comment: вы не ответили на мой первый вопрос: "а выход из `while True` когда?"

Comment: S.Nick скорее всего никогда

Comment: точнее когда я закрою программу

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: я пытался создать простенькую игра на модуле pygame, а это основной игровой цикл поэтому он прекратиться после того как я закрою полностью программу

Comment: я не совсем понял ваше первое объяснение с return var, вы не могли бы отправить код полностью, или объяснить получше ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
number = 150
number2 = 0
#var = False

def fun(num):
#    global var
    if num == 160:                # num
        var = True
    else:
        var = False
    return  var                   # return  

while True:
    if fun(number):
        print('number: yes')

    if fun(number2):
        print('number2: yes')

    number += 1
    number2 += 1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы мне очень помогли

Comment: уже сделал, спасибо что подсказали, это первый мой вопрос на этом сайте

Comment: @MikeSmit пожалуйста